# FadeOut/FadeIn animations before/after ngAnimate

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, css-animations, ng-animate

I have this form on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/juI2wHh5A0nHFG9LEBD8?p=preview) and a struggling with adding a fade animation.

What I want to do is, before the keyframe animation starts have the content fade out. And when the new view appears, I want the the keyframe animation to finish and than an animate.css animation to run (fadeInUp for example).

So the view will animate and then the content inside the view will animate, If somebody can help me with this I would really appreciate it.

my current animation is using the following keyframe animation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideOutLeft {
    0% {
        transform: scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
    }
    20% {
        transform: scaleY(0.01) scaleX(1);
    }
    40% {
        transform: scaleY(0.005) scaleX(0.5);
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scaleY(0.005) scaleX(0.5);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideInRight {
    0% {
        transform: scaleY(0.005) scaleX(0.5);
        background: rgba(0,188,140,1);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        transform: scaleY(0.005) scaleX(0.5);
        background: rgba(0,188,140,1);
        z-index: 1;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    70% {
        transform: scaleY(0.005) scaleX(1);
        background: rgba(0,188,140,1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scaleY(1) scaleX(1);
    }
}
```

Running on ng.enter and ng.leave

```
/* enter animation */
#form-views.ng-enter { 
    -webkit-animation:slideInRight 2s both ease;
    -moz-animation:slideInRight 2s both ease;
    animation:slideInRight 2s both ease; 
}

/* leave animation */
#form-views.ng-leave            { 
    -webkit-animation:slideOutLeft 2s both ease;
    -moz-animation:slideOutLeft 2s both ease;
    animation:slideOutLeft 2s both ease;   
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

I have updated the code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/iV63HMDgOBOgWEgHdGnX?p=preview)

using:

```
#form-views.ng-enter *          {
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn 2s both ease 3s;
    -moz-animation:fadeIn 2s both ease 3s;
    animation:fadeIn 2s both ease 3s;
}

#form-views.ng-leave *          {
    -webkit-animation:fadeOut 0.5s both ease;
    -moz-animation:fadeOut 0.5s both ease;
    animation:fadeOut 0.5s both ease;
}
```

And this is the animation:

```
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeOut { from { opacity:1; } to { opacity:0; } }
```

The code appears and disappearing at the correct time but doesn't animate the opacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try adding separate animation for fadeIn/Out and using the css animation delay to trigger one after the other. E.G:

```
/* enter animation */
#form-views.ng-enter {
    -webkit-animation:slideInRight 2s both ease, fadeIn 1s both ease 2s;
    -moz-animation:slideInRight 2s both ease, fadeIn 1s both ease 2s;
    animation:slideInRight 2s both ease, fadeIn 1s both ease 2s; 
}

/* leave animation */
#form-views.ng-leave            { 
    -webkit-animation:slideOutLeft 2s both ease 1s, fadeOut 1s both ease;
    -moz-animation:slideOutLeft 2s both ease 1s, fadeOut 1s both ease;
    animation:slideOutLeft 2s both ease 1s, fadeOut 1s both ease;   
}
```

and i think you know what the fadeIn and fadeOut animations should be.

**UPDATE:**

[Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/7dohCzLEufZvinH34Abv?p=preview) a plunker with the code working the way I believe you want it to work. In chrome at least. You'll need to use the correct prefixes/no prefixes to get it working in other browsers.

Comment: Interesting, I tried your solution and it seems to be doubling the animation on the ng.enter and ng.leave elements. I have edited the question based on this - but my fades do not seem to be animating - just appearing and disappearing

Comment: so [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/7dohCzLEufZvinH34Abv?p=preview) works on my computer in chrome 43 at least... What I had to do was add a wrapper class to all of the content inside the forms so you could change the opacity of the content without making the background disappear, so that you could still see the shrinking/sliding animations. Also the enter animation is a bit tricky, since the form appears as soon as you click on the button, therefore you need to wait for the leave animation.

Comment: I had to add the `holdAnimationClass` so that ng-leave would remain so the wrapper of the content could still use that class for it's animation. Unfortunately the `ng-enter` class will not listen to animations on the children element

Comment: Yep that works, exactly what I needed. I will test cross-browser in the production code. Thanks for all the help Sir Neuman.